# How get previous value to every item in foreach

Tags: asp.net-core

How get previous value to every item in foreach?
This is what i get:

```
100 200 300 400 500 600 700

100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

This is what i want get:

```
100 200 300 400 500 600 700

0 100 200 300 400 500 600
```

And here is my code:

```
@foreach (var i2 in ViewBag.ce)
{
    @for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.ce.Count - ViewBag.ce.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        var previous = ViewBag.ce[i];
        @(previous)
    }
}
```

Code in controller:

```
var Reward = db.Reward.Where(p => p.Category == 1).Select(p => p.Prize).ToList();
ViewBag.ce = Reward;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you need 2 loops, I think you just need one and handle the special case of the first iteration.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.ce.Count; i++)
{
    if(i != 0){
        var previous = ViewBag.ce[i-1];
    }
    else
    {
        var previous = ViewBag.ce[i];
    }
    @(previous)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. How can I find the current value in this?

Comment: Within the loop, ViewBag.ce[i] is the current item. Feel free to assign it to a variable as you wish and use as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define a reference for a previous item. For sample:

```
int previous = 0; // you could start it with some default value like 0  (in your sample)
@for (var i = 0; i < ViewBag.ce.Count - ViewBag.ce.Count + 1; i++)
{
    // code using previous..

    // define the previous for the next iteration
    previous = ViewBag.ce[i];        
}
```

I am not sure about your loop conditions but see a working sample: https://rextester.com/PZLISI37532

Comment: In this case, I gets exactly the same as mine. Which is 100 for every item in foreach items

Comment: How can i use it or SQL values? Mine 100-700 comes from sql and they are in ViewBag.ce

Comment: Edit your initial post and share more details what do you want to do. What you are adding on the ViewBag?